# React & Bootstrap: returning the value of selected radio button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I've a ButtonGroup as a radio buttons in navigation bar. I'd like to return a value of selected button in certain page. I've not much React experience and I'm a bit lost.

I have two .js-files: sidebar.js and page.js.

sidebar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import history from '../../core/history';

import {
    Radio,
    ButtonGroup,
    Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Sidebar extends Component {

    _onOptionChange(option) {
      this.setState({
          option: option
      });
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <li>
                  <ButtonGroup vertical block data-toggle="buttons">
                    <Button className="btn btn-block" onClick={this._onOptionChange.bind(this, 'optionA')} active={this.state.option === 'optionA'}>Option A</Button>
                    <Button className="btn btn-block" onClick={this._onOptionChange.bind(this, 'optionB')} active={this.state.option === 'optionB'}>Option B</Button>
                    <Button className="btn btn-block" onClick={this._onOptionChange.bind(this, 'optionC')} active={this.state.option === 'optionC'}>Option C</Button>
                  </ButtonGroup>
            </li>
            ...
            ...
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

page.js:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { PageHeader } from 'react-bootstrap';

const title = 'Page';

function displayPage(props, context) {
  context.setTitle(title);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <PageHeader>Title</PageHeader>
        </div>
        <div className="col-lg-6">

        { value of selected radio button }

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

displayPage.contextTypes = { setTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired };
export default displayPage;
```

How could I return the selected value?
Thanks!

Comment: Basically, you need to have some container component that has both of the components inside - Sidebar and the one you need to populate with the selected value. And then have the container handle callbacks and passing values via props.

Answer (score 0):

From the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> The state contains data specific to this component that may change over time.

In your `Sidebar` component, a click on the button will change the internal state of the Sidebar by calling `this.setState({ ... })`.

Consider the use of **[props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)** when designing components:

> Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called "**props**") and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen.

So, in your case - I would think of `Sidebar` as a component that displays a list of options, and receives a callback function as its props. The callback function will be called from the `Sidebar` component by clicking one of the buttons, and will allow you to notify the containing component (the parent) of the click:

```
class SomethingThatUsesSidebar extends Component {
  onSidebarOptionSelect(option) {
      console.log(option);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <Sidebar onOptionSelect={this.onSidebarOptionSelect.bind(this)} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In your `Sidebar` component, you call the callback function like so:

```
class Sidebar extends Component {
    // ...

    _onOptionChange(option) {
        this.props.onOptionSelect(option);
    }

   render() { ... }
}
```